# Move/copy data from one folder to another on AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

I am looking for all the methods for moving/copying the data from one folder to another on AWS S3 bucket.

---

**Method 1: Via AWS CLI** (Most easy)

Download and install awscli on ur instance, I am using here windows([64-bit link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-windows.html)) and run "asw configure" to fill up your configuration and just run this single command on cmd

```
aws s3 cp s3://from-source/ s3://to-destination/ --recursive
```

Here cp for copy and recursive to copy all files

---

**Method 2: Via AWS CLI using python**

```
import os
import awscli
if os.environ.get('LC_CTYPE', '') == 'UTF-8':
    os.environ['LC_CTYPE'] = 'en_US.UTF-8'

from awscli.clidriver import create_clidriver
driver = create_clidriver()
driver.main('s3 mv s3://staging/AwsTesting/research/    s3://staging/AwsTesting/research_archive/ --recursive'.split())
```

Even this worked for me perfectly

---

**Method 3: Via Boto using python**

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'staging',
    'Key': '/AwsTesting/research/'
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'staging', '/AwsTesting/research_archive/')
```

With my understanding I have assumed the 'key' for bucket is just the folder prefix so I have mentioned the folder path here

Error:

> Invalid bucket name "s3://staging": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,255}$"

Even I changed it to simple bucket name as "staging" but no success.

---

How can I understand bucket connectivity via boto and the concept of this key?

Comment: I see no reason in the docs to believe that `s3.meta.client.copy` copies anything other than a single object.  *"Copy an object from one S3 location to another.  This is a managed transfer which will perform a multipart copy in multiple threads if necessary."*  A "multipart copy" does not mean multiple objects.  It means that a single object is copied using multiple HTTP transactions, each handling different byte ranges.

Comment: s3 bucket names have to be globally unique, so you cannot have a bucket of the same name as someone else... by now if noone already owns the single s3 bucket called 'staging' I'd be very surprised!

Answer (score 14):

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'staging',
    'Key': 'AwsTesting/research/filename.csv'
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'staging', 'AwsTesting/')
```

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to using `cp` with the CLI is `sync` - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket s3://mybucket2
```

It will essentially do the same thing.

Comment: Is it possible to mention number of files to move ?

Comment: @Karthik I don't believe so (the doc I linked will have all the answers you seek), you can specify a prefix and either include or exclude files/prefixes I believe but not an arbitrary number.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following snippet which is working.

```
def s3candidateavtarcopy(old,new):
try:
    response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket = s3_candidate_bucket,Prefix=old)
    keycount = response['KeyCount']
    if(keycount > 0):
        for key in response['Contents']:
            file = key['Key']
            try:
                output = file.split(old)
                newfile = new + output[1]
                input_source = {'Bucket': s3_candidate_bucket,'Key' : file }
                s3_resource.Object(s3_candidate_bucket,newfile).copy_from(CopySource=input_source)
            except ClientError as e:
                print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
            else:
                print('Success')
    else:
        print('No matching records')
except ClientError as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
else:
    print('Operatio completed')
```